# Which function returns a registry value?

Tags: winapi, registry

[Retrieving Data from the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/retrieving-data-from-the-registry) is confusing me.  All I want is to retrieve the value of a particular registry key.  Which one of the functions do I use?

Comment: `RegQueryValueExW` if you know key and value name

Comment: I do.  
Thank You!

Comment: @Todd there is also [`RegGetValueW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew), which is better to use than `RegQueryValueExW()` when reading string values, as it handles null terminators in a safer manner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the documentation that you linked to:

> An application can use the [RegEnumValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regenumvaluea) function to enumerate the values for a given key, **and [RegQueryValueEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa) function to retrieve a particular value for a key.**